# Getting the Speed of the User - getSpeed and casting

Tags: android, gps, location, google-play-services

I am currently trying to get the speed of a user using the GPS (Google Play Location Services).

However, the problem with my code is that the speed is stuck on a very small number - going down to 1.9^E18, basically 0. This value doesn't change even though I move around.

I am currently trying to calculate the speed of the user manually through using speed and time stamps. However, I have also found a function called getSpeed(). I was considering to use it, but there were many complaints I found here that said that it always returned zero.

**Firstly - is getSpeed() only used for mock locations, or can it be used safely with location objects obtained by the GPS?**

Secondly if getSpeed does not work, I will need to continue obtaining the speed manually. I believe there may be problems with the casting. **Can someone help in finding the problem of my current method?**

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        location.getLatitude();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (settings == null) {
            settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        }

        int TimeDifference = (int) (location.getTime() - OldLocation.getTime());
        int distance = (int) OldLocation.distanceTo(location);

        double speed = distance / TimeDifference;

        if (LowerLimit < speed && speed < UpperLimit) {
            TimeInstance += TimeDifference;
        }

        if (TimeInstance>TimeLimit) {
            if (!dialogShown) {
                dialogShown = true;
                ViolationMessage();
                TimeInstance = 0;
            }
            else {
                TimeInstance = 0;
            }
        }
        OldLocation = location;
    }
```

Comment: Well right now your speed is in meters per milisecond, so no wonder you're getting very low values. Type in google `10 km/h to m/ms` and see what you get. And yes getSpeed always returns 0, it's there only for you if you wanted to set calculated speed with setSpeed to location object.

Comment: But 1.9 * 10 to the power of 19 is absurdly slow, isn't it? Even if I do change it to m/s, wouldn't it still make only a tiny difference?

Comment: Why don't you just debug or log variables to see what values you get? So you can know if it's distance or TimeDifference affecting speed that much.

Comment: Last time I tried, it was distance that was the problem. I was getting consistently 0.01 m even when I was moving.

Comment: Try `double speed = (double) distance / TimeDifference` or just change distance to double/float, since that is what `distanceTo` returns.

Comment: Alright - I'll do that as soon as I can move around. Thanks for the advice though!